# rtabmap ignore odometry

Tags: navigation, kinect, roomba, ros-kinetic, rtabmap-odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can i set rtabmap_ros to ignore the odometry of the robot?
At this moment the odometry of the robot is not good enough and will start to conflict with rtabmap resulting in a robot not knowing its position.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248629/rtabmap-ignore-odometry/) by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2016-11-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

rtabmap_ros requires odometry to work. The odometry can come from the robot (wheel odometry) or any other sources like visual odometry. rtabmap_ros has a [rgbd_odometry](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#rgbd_odometry) node that can be used to generate visual odometry for convenience. You will have to disable odometry from your robot (at least the TF) if you use another source of odometry.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dox](https://answers.ros.org/users/34329/dox/) on 2018-08-01**:
Hi! I'm trying to use rgbd_odometry instead of wheel odom. Do you have any suggestions on how to disable odom from robot in TF? I also posted a question [here](https://bit.ly/2OwvuMR).

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2018-08-01**:
you may comment this line: https://github.com/amor-ros-pkg/rosaria/blob/aa8d5f7faf4b2bc57bea2c597efee1b9a79953ea/RosAria.cpp#L567